# ssh key reset every computer restart

Tags: ssh, openssh, github

Every time I restart my computer I have to ssh-add my ssh key.  I already have ssh key added on github.
Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an alias in your ssh config. For example:

```
    Host example.github.com
            HostName github.com
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example
```

Make sure your git remote references the ssh alias "example.github.com". The "IdentityFile" directive should point to the path where you plan on storing your private key. This tells ssh which key to associate with the alias.

Comment: is there an example for that?  I am fairly new to github.  I don't even know where to find the ssh config. Ty for your reply.

Comment: By default only the global config exists. Generally people create a user ssh config in their home directory like "~/.ssh/config". Here are several example configs. http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-customize-ssh-client